# compact form of many for loop in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, nested-for-loop

I have a piece of code as follows, and the number of `for` loops is determined by `n` which is known at compile time. Each `for` loop iterates over the values 0 and 1. Currently, my code looks something like this

```
for(int in=0;in<2;in++){
    for(int in_1=0;in_1<2;in_1++){
        for(int in_2=0;in_2<2;in_2++){
          // ... n times
            for(int i2=0;i2<2;i2++){
               for(int i1=0;i1<2;i1++){
                   d[in][in_1][in_2]...[i2][i1] =updown(in)+updown(in_1)+...+updown(i1);
               }
            }
          // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Now my question is whether one can write it in a more compact form.

Comment: A quintuple-nested loop?  Why do you need a "compact form"?  What problem would this "compact form" solve?

Comment: I'm quite positive that this can be rewritten in compact form simply by reimplementing whatever this is trying to accomplish, from the ground up. A never-ending abyss of `for` loops is usually not the problem, the problem usually turns out to be bad design, with the `for` loops being the manifestation of the bad design.

Comment: I think he wants to loop over all variables simultaneously...

Comment: Recursive function should be useful instead of nested `for`, but it looks difficult to implement meaningful variable number of `[]`s.

Comment: The `n` bits `in_k` can be interpreted as the representation of one integer less than `2^n`. This allows easily to work with a 1-D array (vector) `d[.]` and then to implement a recursive function, as suggested by @MikeCAT

Comment: I don't think that the proposed duplicate is really one, as here the variables are bits. However, I am quite sure that another exact duplicate must exist on SO.

Comment: thanks, @Damien. this can be a solution. Could you please explain a little a bit more in detail, thanks?

Comment: Is `n` known at compile time or is only known at run-time?

Comment: @cigien ```n``` is fixed in the main code.

Comment: @Ghoti It is difficult to give too much details in comments. Moreover, here you have a complexity O(n^2). I am convinced that it must be possible to get a much lower complexity. For example, consider `f(val, n) = updown(val%2) + f(val/2, n-1)` and `f(val, 0) = 0`

Comment: In that case, the duplicate target addresses your question. You can do what you want with the loop indices once you generate them conveniently.

Comment: @cigien The duplicate only solution uses an external library. It does not take into account the binary aspect, nor the special form of the function to calculate here. A much more efficient solution is clearly possible for the specific question in the post here.

Comment: @Damien Oh, I don't notice that the loop indices only ever have the value 0 or 1. Yeah, this is different from the target. Reopening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `n` bits `in_k` can be interpreted as the representation of one integer less than `2^n`.

This allows easily to work with a 1-D array (vector) `d[.]`.

In practice, an interger `j` corresponds to

```
j = in[0] + 2*in[1] + ... + 2^n-1*in[n-1]
```

Moreover, a direct implementation is O(NlogN). (N = 2^n)

A recursive solution is possible, for example using

```
f(val, n) = updown(val%2) + f(val/2, n-1) and f(val, 0) = 0.
```

This would correspond to a O(N) complexity, at the condition to introduce memoization, not implemented here.

Result:

```
0 : 0
1 : 1
2 : 1
3 : 2
4 : 1
5 : 2
6 : 2
7 : 3
8 : 1
9 : 2
10 : 2
11 : 3
12 : 2
13 : 3
14 : 3
15 : 4
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int up_down (int b) {
    if (b) return 1;
    return 0;
}

int f(int val, int n) {
    if (n < 0) return 0;
    return up_down (val%2) + f(val/2, n-1);
}

int main() {
    const int n = 4;
    int size = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) size *= 2;
    std::vector<int> d(size, 0);
    
    for (int i = 0; i  < size; ++i) {
        d[i] = f(i, n);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        std::cout << i << " : " << d[i] << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

As mentioned above, the recursive approach allows a O(N) complexity, at the condition to implement memoization.

Another possibility is to use a simple iterative approach, in order to get this O(N) complexity.
(here N represents to total number of data)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int up_down (int b) {
    if (b) return 1;
    return 0;
}
int main() {
    const int n = 4;
    int size = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) size *= 2;
    std::vector<int> d(size, 0);
    
    int size_block = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i  < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = size_block-1; j >= 0; --j) {
            d[2*j+1] = d[j] + up_down(1);
            d[2*j] = d[j] + up_down(0);
        }
        size_block *= 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        std::cout << i << " : " << d[i] << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Artyer I modified already the post. It is O(1) for each calculated value, so O(N) globally. I did not know about `std::popcount(.)`. It simplifies everything effectively. But is this function really O(1)?

Answer (score 2):

You can refactor your code slightly like this:

```cpp
for(int in=0;in<2;in++) {
    auto& dn = d[in];
    auto updown_n = updown(in);
    for(int in_1=0;in_1<2;in_1++) {
        // dn_1 == d[in][in_1]
        auto& dn_1 = dn[in_1];
        // updown_n_1 == updown(in)+updown(in_1)
        auto updown_n_1 = updown_n + updown(in_1);
        for(int in_2=0;in_2<2;in_2++) {
            // dn_2 == d[in][in_1][in_2]
            auto& dn_2 = dn_1[in_2];
            // updown_n_2 == updown(in)+updown(in_1)+updown(in_2)
            auto updown_n_2 = updown_n_1 + updown(in_2);
                     .
                     .
                     .
            for(int i2=0;i2<2;i1++) {
               // d2 == d[in][in_1][in_2]...[i2]
               auto& d2 = d3[i2];
               // updown_2 = updown(in)+updown(in_1)+updown(in_2)+...+updown(i2)
               auto updown_2 = updown_3 + updown(i2);
               for(int i1=0;i1<2;i1++) {
                   // d1 == d[in][in_1][in_2]...[i2][i1]
                   auto& d1 = d2[i1];
                   // updown_1 = updown(in)+updown(in_1)+updown(in_2)+...+updown(i2)+updown(i1)
                   auto updown_1 = updown_2 + updown(i1);

                   // d[in][in_1][in_2]...[i2][i1] = updown(in)+updown(in_1)+...+updown(i1);
                   d1 = updown_1;
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And make this into a recursive function now:

```cpp
template<std::size_t N, typename T>
void loop(T& d) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        loop<N-1>(d[i], updown(i));
    }
}

template<std::size_t N, typename T, typename U>
typename std::enable_if<N != 0>::type loop(T& d, U updown_result) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        loop<N-1>(d[i], updown_result + updown(i));
    }
}

template<std::size_t N, typename T, typename U>
typename std::enable_if<N == 0>::type loop(T& d, U updown_result) {
    d = updown_result;
}
```

If your type is `int d[2][2][2]...[2][2];` or `int*****... d;`, you can also stop when the type isn't an array or pointer instead of manually specifying `N` (or change for whatever the type of `d[0][0][0]...[0][0]` is)

Here's a version that does that with a recursive lambda:

```cpp
auto loop = [](auto& self, auto& d, auto updown_result) -> void {
    using d_t = typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<decltype(d)>::type>::type;
    if constexpr (!std::is_array<d_t>::value && !std::is_pointer<d_t>::value) {
        // Last level of nesting
        d = updown_result;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
            self(self, d[i], updown_result + updown(i));
        }
    }
};
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    loop(loop, d[i], updown(i));
}
```

Comment: @Jay I hope you see that your comment is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that it is a multi-dimensional matrix. You may have to solve it mathematically first and then write the respective equations in the program.